# Where is my themes folder on windows 10?

Tags: sublimetext3

I am trying to change the color of my indents but I can not find my themes folder at all, both in the programs folder and the %appData% folder. I only have the one theme which does not change anything when I edit it.

[image]

I want to change the indents to have the following colors...

```
<key>guide</key>
<string>#FF0000</string>
<key>stackGuide</key>
<string>#00FF00</string>
<key>activeGuide</key>
<string>#0000FF</string>
```

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: Many ST3 Packages are inside zip folders. I would recommend the [PackageResourceViewer](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) to navigate to your colorscheme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a value assigned to the `"theme"` key in your `Preferences.sublime-settings` file?

If not, the default setting is `"theme": "Default.sublime-theme"`

You can edit `Default.sublime-theme` with the following process:

---

---

### **Install:**

### [PackageResourceViewer](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer)

---

### **Open the command palette & run:**

`PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource`

### **Select:**

`Theme - Default`

---

### Update & Save `Default.sublime-theme`

SublimeText will automatically create a user instance of the file, leaving the original file intact.
The user instance will override the original file.